# Is it possible to capture a type template into a template argument?

Tags: c++, templates, generics, stl, containers

Is it possible to capture a template *from* a template argument i.e.  have a nested template specifier with a template argument that holds the template type?

```
template< typename T, typename Label = std::string>
class foo {
    // ...
};

template <
            template < typename C, typename T > typename C<T>,
            // ...
            typename Label = std::string
         >
class bar {
    // ...
    C< foo< T, Label > > A;
};
```

For instance, I'd like to pass a generic STL container (`std::vector< int >`) as template argument, but declare a member of the same meta-type (`std::vector`) but with different value type (`foo< int >`) i.e. `std::vector< foo< int > >`. It may seem convoluted, but it would be helpful to not hardcode the type of STL container.

For context, I'm aiming at a generic container adapter/wrapper (in the line of `std::stack` or `std::queue`) that provides some higher-level functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can just use template specialization:

```
#include <string>

template<typename T, typename Label = std::string>
class foo {};

template <class T, typename Label = std::string>
class bar;

template <template<class...> class C, typename T, typename Label>
class bar<C<T>, Label> {
  C<foo<T, Label>> A;
};
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/sGMbnv9aG)

Comment: Why you use mixed `class` and `typename` in the templates?

Comment: @BotondHorváth - I'm guessing it's because (a) they are interchangeable and (b) to signal to users what parameter should be a given a class type to make the code work.

Comment: This was pretty much what I was looking for. Is there, however, a way to provide a default argument to `C`?

Comment: The first template parameter of `bar` is a *type*, not a *template*, which means that it has been instantiated, so it does not make sense to provide default parameters for it.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer's approach can be generalized as a reusable template rebinder:

```
template<typename T>
struct rebinder;

template<template<typename...> typename T, typename... Args>
struct rebinder<T<Args...>> {
  template<typename... Us>
  using rebind = T<Us...>;
};

template<typename T, typename... Us>
using rebound = rebinder<T>::template rebind<Us...>;

// example:
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
struct MyStruct {
    rebound<T, float> vec;
};

int main() {
    MyStruct<std::vector<int>> x;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::vector<float>, decltype(x.vec)>);
}
```

see on [godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/sY6TdvTda)